# Query works on database A but not on B

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'v got the following query:

```
SELECT
    nr
    , txt = info.result
FROM
    dbo.anlagen AS a
    CROSS APPLY
     ocAuxiliary.splitString(
        ISNULL(
            ocAuxiliary.parseRTF(a.notiz)
            ,'')
     ,80)
      AS info
```

which works fine on on database, but not on another. The functions / SPROCS are created by code and therefore deterministic.

Error on B is: 
Meldung 102, Ebene 15, Status 1, Zeile 9
Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von '.'.
( Wrong Syntax near '.'.)

Just calling the used functions/SPROCS works fine also:

On DB A

```
SELECT * from ocAuxiliary.splitString('1234567890', 3)
```

returns

```
iteration   result
1   123
2   456
3   789
4   0
```

as it does on DB B.

On DB A

```
select ocAuxiliary.parseRTF('{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1031\fs20 12 ')
```

returns 12

as it does on DB B.

I simply don't see the mistake.

Comment: What compatibility mode are the two databases in?

Comment: B is 80 (the one where it doesn't work), A is 100 - changed B to 100 did all the magic. Please write your comment as answer, so i can accept it! Thx!

Comment: Yep. `CROSS APPLY` doesn't work on 80.